# How can you use a WebSocket client in a Flutter app?

Tags: websocket, flutter

Is there a way to open a WebSocket client in a Flutter app? Flutter doesn't allow you to import dart:html, which is the normal way of using a WebSocket client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Flutter you can use `dart:io` which supports WebSocket

https://api.dartlang.org/stable/1.24.2/dart-io/WebSocket-class.html

Comment: As far as I can tell from the docs and examples, this is just the server.

Comment: Flutter us pretty much the same as what runs on the server, except reflection which is server-only in Dart 2.0.0.

Comment: From https://flutter.io/faq/#can-flutter-run-any-dart-code: Flutter should be able to run most Dart code that does not import (transitively, or directly) dart:mirrors or dart:html. The WebSocket client is in dart:html.

Comment: Right, I somehow assumed it's clear that `dart:html` can't be used in Flutter, but I agree it's definitely worth mentioning. So, does this answer your question?

Comment: Yup, it does. The dart:html WebSocket client may be easier to use but the dart:io client works as well.